# ASM4/5: How can I embedded source code in ASM4/5

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm

I am about to transform(manipulate) a lot of classes and to allow easy debugging and transparent communication of the changes applied to the code, I want to add java source code equivalent of the manipulated class.

In order to add java code I would be able to use existing source code and manipulate it in parallel. Then I need to store it along with the class.

Visiting the class file format for JDK 8, I noticed that no attribute exists to directly embed source code. Remembering the old times it was possible to include the source code within a class file. What do I miss? (I only found the attribute for specifying a source file). Also the option in the compiler tab of Eclipse does only show options to embed file names... .

Beside seaming to store source files separately, I wonder if it is feasible to reverse engineer (decompile) the class file. If one provide information about local names and parameter names, this might even be a better option.

The ASM documentation stated out that a tool is available to even decompile byte code.

Does anyone has some insights or experiences to share on this matter?

Comment: I don’t know of any standard way of embedding source code and can’t remember seeing such a thing in a specification throughout Java 1.1 to Java 8. Even if such thing existed, the absence of tools being capable of reading it out again, made it useless (today). On the other hand, if you want to extract it with your own tools, it doesn’t need to be a standard; adding custom attributes is allowed. Decompiling is a completely different matter and it’s not clear to me how it is supposed to help you on that issue.

Comment: Well I want to produce the output leaving the local names and parameter names intact and then just decompile the current byte [] content of the class getting some kind of a source map and storing it in a file, link the file with the class and store the correct line numbers. So it should be possible to provide human readable information during debugging. By using a decent decompiler the debugging session should be the way one would expected not hiding all the manipulations making the source navigatable and debuggable.

Comment: Well, if you can express your transformations in source code, doing so and recompiling these source is far better than attempting to decompile manipulated byte code. I wouldn’t expect convincing output from decompilers (for any non-trivial code). Besides that, running a decompiler in advance doesn’t offer any advantage over running a decompiler once a debugging session started. But I guess, I simply don’t know enough about the kind of transformations you are going to perform, to make a useful suggestion…

Comment: I had to decompile (reverse engineer) a Swing application including the backend once (it was not obfuscated). It was absolutely stunning how well it worked. Did not even noticed it beside the default formatting.

Comment: I have a task where I denormalize the complete object graph in order to allow advanced type reloading. Easy done but hard to debug. Maybe the best would be slicing a class up attach the appropriated source code (AST) and transform everything in conjunction. Would be the easiest way to avoid the decompile cycle and allow comments to each modification. But might hit a wall with ASM here.